# Tinymce rails image upload - how to delete images if post isn't created

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, tinymce, image-uploading, tinymce-4

Basically I fallowed this documentation:  [tinymce rails image upload](https://github.com/PerfectlyNormal/tinymce-rails-imageupload)

It works, but the problem is that It saves every image in the db before the actual post is created. Thus even if the post isn't finished or saved, the images still remain on the server. And that is just waisting space on the server.

Does anyone know a better way for image upload with tinymce ?